# C# Silverlight - What loads first? The XAML Bindings or the Event Handlers in the code behind?

Tags: c#, winforms, silverlight, event-handling

In C#, What loads first? The XAML Bindings in the window panel .xaml file or the Event Handlers in the code behind .xaml.cs file?

Comment: WinForms doesn't use XAML.

Comment: Should be fairly simple to find out with some breakpoints?

Comment: So, are you using Windows Forms, WPF, or SilverLight?

Comment: Or Windows Store apps...

Comment: i am using silverlight. which i assume now is different from win forms, even tho the functionality is the exact same , save the bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the .cs does. It calls `InitializeComponent()` which creates and binds your controls.

***Proof***

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Empty);
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Comment: ah yes, so the event handlers in the cs will be created before the bindings to view models or event handlers are created. sounds good.

i was attempting to bind a loaded event of a window to a property in a view model class, with no luck of course.